# contact form 7 — Как сделать разные значения radio input у текста и у value?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Хочу чтоб в форме можно было выбрать на какую почту отправлять но мне нужно чтобы value и текст отличались, как такое сделать в form 7?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаблон формы:**
[radio send-email default:1 "email1@mail.ru" "email2@mail.ru"]

**Шаблон отправки:**
Кому:
[send-email]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [ссылка](https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/) на документацию по форм 7 где есть пример точно такого же функционала но с использованием селекта, не пробовал но думаю и с радиокнопками тоже работает такой пример, разделение значения и свойства через |

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
                    "Sales|sales@example.com"
                    "Support|support@example.com"]
```